# Div is not taking its height

Tags: html, css, height

I want to have two classes of `<div>` representing a cup. There is one big cup and a bunch of small cups. But my problem is that the `<div>` is not taking the height I gave it. Since I want to size down the smaller cups I do not want to use `min-height` for `.cup` in CSS.

Here is my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600&display=swap');
:root {
  --border-color: #144fc6;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #3494e4;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 400px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.cup {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 4px solid var(--border-color);
  color: var(--border-color);
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
  height: 330px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cup.cup-small {
  width: 50px;
  height: 95px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PK0gIY59xJ8Co8+NEgFZ+L0AZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY&wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Drink Water</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Drink Water</h1>

  <h3>Goal: 2 Liters</h3>

  <div class="cup">
    <div class="remained" id="remained">
      <span id="'Liters">1.5L</span>
      <small>Remained</small>
    </div>

    <div class="percentage" id="percentage">
      20%
    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="text">
    Select how many glasses of water tat you have drank.
  </p>

  <div class="cup cup-small full">
    250 ml
  </div>
  <div class="cup cup-small full">
    250 ml
  </div>
  <div class="cup cup-small">
    250 ml
  </div>
  <div class="cup cup-small">
    250 ml
  </div>
  <div class="cup cup-small">
    250 ml
  </div>
  <div class="cup cup-small">
    250 ml
  </div>
  <div class="cup cup-small">
    250 ml
  </div>
  <div class="cup cup-small">
    250 ml
  </div>


  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any idea why the container just takes some kind of `min-height` instead of the one I gave it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove display flex from body tag. If you explain what you need exactly, I can help you

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600&display=swap');
:root {
  --border-color: #144fc6;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #3494e4;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 400px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 10px;
  justify-content:center;

}

.cup {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 4px solid var(--border-color);
  color: var(--border-color);
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
  height: 330px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cup.cup-small {
  width: 50px;
  height: 95px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PK0gIY59xJ8Co8+NEgFZ+L0AZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY&wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Drink Water</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Drink Water</h1>

  <h3>Goal: 2 Liters</h3>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cup">
      <div class="remained" id="remained">
        <span id="'Liters">1.5L</span>
        <small>Remained</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="percentage" id="percentage">
      20%
    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="text">
    Select how many glasses of water tat you have drank.
  </p>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="cup cup-small full">
      250 ml
    </div>
    <div class="cup cup-small full">
      250 ml
    </div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">
      250 ml
    </div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">
      250 ml
    </div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">
      250 ml
    </div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">
      250 ml
    </div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">
      250 ml
    </div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">
      250 ml
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this did the job but can you explain to me way display: flex has this effect?

Answer (score 0):

So what helped was to wrap an additional div around all the small-cup divs and put its atrribute display to flex. Still I am wondering why it did the job and why it did not work before. Because it even changed the height of the first div that represents the big one and which is not wrapped by the div I added. I hope that makes sence.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Hieght` in your body css.
Now remember, body is in a way superior, so the properties of body is being used.